# How can I print out the maximum value by using for loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the maximum amount of value(index 4) between 42000,22000,35000 and 18000.

```
 employee={'1001':['Amy',45,'F','LA',42000],
           '1002':['Brian',26,'M','MN',22000],
           '1003':['Carrie',30,'F','TX',35000],
           '1004':['Diana',22,'F','AZ',18000]}
```

Expectation: 42000

My work:

```
for employee_id,info in employee:
    for i in info:
        print(max(info[4]))
```

And it says ERROR (ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2))
Thanks for helping.

Comment: As for the particular error, you'll need to use `for ... in employee.items()`… But this code won't print the *maximum* value anyway. Does it have to be a for loop? `print(max(i[4] for i in employee.values()))` would do just fine…

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print(max([employee[i][4] for i in employee]))
```

Output:

```
42000
```

Comment: The `[]` are superfluous. Iterating over the key and then using that to lookup the value is unnecessarily complicated; `i[4] for i in employee.values()` would do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
maximum = 0

for value in employee.values(): 
    maximum = max(maximum, value[4])

print(maximum)
```

Comment: How can I print out the name of the person who has the highest salary without directly typing the name?

Comment: you can do this:

```
maximum = 0
name = ""

for value in employee.values(): 
    maximum = max(maximum, value[4])
    
    if value[4] == maximum: 
        name = value[0]
```

@Nappy

Comment: if I want to add up all the values in the fourth column, should I do like this? total=sum(total,i[1])

Comment: you can add a new variable `sum = 0` before the for loop and just add this line in the loop: `sum += value[4]`.

Comment: And if I want to add up all the values in the second column, I tried to do this but it ends up being an error...

summ=0

for value in employee.values(): 
    summ += value[2]
print(summ)

Comment: summ += value[1] will do this. @Nappy

Comment: I would also like to find the average salary of M and F. I did something like this but I got stuck.. salary is the fourth index in each value.

salary_F=0
salary_M=0

for i in employee.values():
    if i[2]=='F':
        salary_F=salary_F+i[4]
        print(salary_F/len(i[2])
        
    else:
        salary_M=salary_M+i[4]
        print(salary_M/len(i[2])

Comment: you can make two lists: salary_F = [] salary_M = [] and inside the loop, do if value[2] == "F": salary_F.append(value[4]) else: salary_M.append(value[4]). After the for loop, you can do: avg_F = sum(salary_F)/len(salary_F) and avg_M = sum(salary_M)/len(salary_M).

and, upvote the answers you got helped with. @Nappy

Comment: Hi @fayez, I am still working on this question. 

I understand how to print out the total number of each state (column index 3), but how can I do for the lived-in XX part without hard-coding it?

if the data change to this:
 employee={'1001':['Amy',45,'F','LA',42000],
           '1002':['Brian',26,'M','MN',22000],
           '1003':['Carrie',30,'F','MN',35000],
           '1004':['Diana',22,'F','AZ',18000]}

Expected output:

There are XX employee(s) lived in XX
There are XX employee(s) lived in XX
There are XX employee(s) lived in XX

Comment: I cann't understand your question, please be more specific @Nappy

Comment: New data:
`employee={'1001':['Amy',45,'F','LA',42000], '1002':['Brian',26,'M','MN',22000], '1003':['Carrie',30,'F','MN',35000], '1004':['Diana',22,'F','AZ',18000]} `

Expected output:

Expected Output:

`There are 2 employee(s) lived in MN
There are 1 employee(s) lived in LA
There are 1 employee(s) lived in AZ`

Wondering how to get this result, thanks a lot!

Comment: you should `import itertools` and then run a for loop like this: 
`for loc, members in itertools.groupby(employee.values(), key= lambda l: l[3]):
    print(f"There are {len(list(members))} employee(s) live(s) in {loc}.")
`
upvote the answers you got helped with, please! @Nappy

Comment: is there any easier method? such as using for loop? Thanks! @fayez

Comment: yes you can do this: 
`for employee in employees.values():
    if employee[3] in groups.keys(): 
        groups[employee[3]] += 1

    else: 
        groups[employee[3]] = 1`

Comment: But isn't `groups[employee[3]]` wordings? How can it do calculations?

As for the printing part:
I tried to do this but I am not sure about it...How should I change it? Thanks!
`print("There are",(missing),"employee(s) lived in",employee[i][3])`

Comment: At this point I am not gonna help. the answer is already in my previous comment. Figure that out. Keep learning. @Nappy